# How to get stderr after stdout when using system(intern = TRUE)?

Tags: r, windows

I am trying to capture the `output` of a command (`exiftool -n -csv -GPSAltitude X:/dir1/dir2/`) using *R*'s *base* `output <- system(command,  intern = TRUE)` function.

Technically, it does what it promises, but the result is still unexpected by me:

```
...
[289] "X:/dir1/dir2/20288_D.JPG,87.037"
[290] "X:/dir1/dir2/0289_D.JPG,87.06"
[291] "X:/dir1    1 directories scanned"
[292] "  303 image files read"
[293] "/dir2/0290_D.JPG,87.085"
[294] "X:/dir1/dir2/0291_D.JPG,87.154"
[295] "X:/dir1/dir2/0292_D.JPG,87.172"
...
```

If I run the same program in *Windows*' *cmd* shell, I only get the *summary text* "1 directories scanned..." at the end, which is what I expected from *R*'s `system` as well. I figured in *R*, by using `system`'s `ignore.stderr = FALSE` that, the *summary text* is sent as *stderr* by the *exiftool* command.

Some workarounds are obvious, like running the command twice, with `ignore.stderr` and `ignore.stdout` set to `TRUE`, alternatively. Or, output to an external file and then read that in R.

I would like to know if there is an actual fix, or if the *stdout* before *stderr* order is not guaranteed, so I should just not expect it.

Comment: The order is *definitely* not guaranteed. These are two independent streams that are written to simultaneously, with independent buffers, and the way they are interleaved if you merge the output is completely arbitrary. The fact that Windows cmd does it one way and `system()` in R does it another way is not surprising, and the order isn’t even deterministic *within the same application!* — So don’t rely on it. The real solution would be to separately capture stdout and stderr. `system` does not allow this, but `system2` does (via detours to files, unfortunately).

Comment: Thanks. I believe the first part of your comment is as good as an answer can get.  Only an authoritative source would make it perfect. As about `system()` not being able to separately capture *stdout* and *stderr*, unless I'm misunderstanding your point, I beg to differ. It can, but only one at a time, via `ignore.stdout` or `ignore.stderr` being set to `TRUE`, alternatively. In fact, as I [recently read](https://ro-che.info/articles/2020-12-11-r-system2), `system2` is just a wrapper of `system`. So both have the same capability, albeit with different usages.

Comment: What I meant is that `system()` can’t *capture* both stdout and stderr separately. The only way to separate them is to discard one of them. You’re right that you *could* do the same with `system` by manipulating the command itself; that’s how `system2` implements this. Incidentally, the implementation of this function is *insane*. But that’s what we’re stuck with, unless you want to use a package; in which case I recommend [‘processx’](https://processx.r-lib.org/reference/run.html), which is a lot more sane.